# Most pythonic way to check if an item is not a list then make it into a list?

Tags: python, data-structures

I am writing a method that can take in a *scalar* *or* a *list* of items.  The first thing that I want to do in the method is to ensure that I am working with a list.  I want to know the most pythonic way of doing that.  Currently I am doing:

```
def print_item_or_list(list_or_item):
    if not isinstance(list_or_item, (list, tuple)):
        list_or_item = [list_or_item]

    # Now I can consistently work with an iterable
    for item in list_or_item:
         print item
```

Is there a more idiomatic way?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use the `iter()` function that throw `TypeError` if is not iterable.

Comment: The usual objections is that strings are iterable, so calling `iter()` doesn't distinguish them. There's really no "Pythonic" way to do this, because it's a bad API to begin with.

Comment: @gipi - lists are iterable too, thats not what he's looking for IMO.

Comment: Why not just pass a list of arguments: def print_item_or_list(*arg)

Comment: If you want to check for any iterable use `from collections import Iterable`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: `isinstance("foo", collections.Iterable) == True`

Comment: @IfLoop, `and not isinstance("foo",basestring)`

Comment: Why not just do `hasattr("foo", "__iter__")`? This returns false for strings, ints, and doubles while yielding true for sets, lists, and dictionaries. Assuming this is Python 2.x it should yield the same results as `collections.Iterable` without the need to import.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the way its done in Python (or the way I've done it) is to use simply use the variable as a list, then handle the error. This can be done with `try...except` block as show below:

```
def tryExceptExample(data):

    try:
        for a in data:    #or whatever code you want to run
            print a

    except TypeError:
        print "Invalid data"   #code you want to run if code in try block fails

    finally:
        print "fin"    #optional branch which always runs
```

**Sample Output:**

```
>>> tryExceptExample([1,2,3])
1
2
3
fin
>>> tryExceptExample("abcd")
a
b
c
d
fin
>>> tryExceptExample(5)
Invalid data
fin
```

**Some Things to Note:**

- The code in the `try` branch will run until it hits an error, then immediatly proceed to `except`, meaning all lines before an error execute.  For this reason, try to keep the number of lines in this branch to a minimum
- Here the `except` branch is shown with a `TypeError`.  This means only `TypeErrors` will be "caught" by this branch and any other errors will be thrown normally.  You can have as many `except` branches as needed for as many errors as you want to catch.  You can also have a "bare" `except` branch which will catch all errors, but this is considered poor form and non-pythonic

Comment: for lists this would fail.

Comment: If you pass a string as input, then it gets printed `len(astr)` times. That seems wrong.

Comment: Yeah, meant to have ```print a``` instead of ```print data```, its been corrected

Answer (score 1):

as Wooble says, your function is not idiomatic in the first place.  consider:

```
def print_one_item(the_item):
    return print_many_items([the_item])

def print_many_items(the_items):
    for an_item in the_items:
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can `type()` function as in

```
if type(some_list) is not list:
    handle
```

Comment: In general I believe `isinstance` is preferred because it is able to handle inheritance.